# ( Is there a / How can I add ) a shortcut that will close an xml element in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

So when I type < in IntelliJ I will get:

```
<table
```

suggestions. Then when I click on SPACE I will get "name" suggestion and my cursor will move in between the double quotes:

```
<table name=""
```

Now my cursor is in between the quotes. I will type the table name..

```
<table name="someTable"
```

Now the cursor is next to e and before ".

How can I add a shortcut that will make this automatically:

```
<table name="someTable" />
```

and move the cursor to end of the line?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ can do this automatically for you, if you go to:

File | Settings | IDE Settings | Editor - Smart Keys

And ensure `Automatically insert closing tag` is checked.

This will insert a closing tag as soon as you type an opening tag.

You can also press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for xml completion as well.